# getting error message from liquibase executor in the spring app: liquibase included file **** is not a recognized file type

Tags: liquibase

The fragment of the master.xml config is:

```
   <include file="config/liquibase/changelog/20190925144235_added_entity_constraints_Order.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>
    <include file="config/liquibase/changelog/20200322165550_added_entity_constraints_BlogEntry.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>
    <include file="config/liquibase/changelog/20200425093313_updated_entity_Teacher" relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>
    <!-- jhipster-needle-liquibase-add-constraints-changelog - JHipster will add liquibase constraints changelogs here -->
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of the problem was missing the *.xml extension in the filename:

```
config/liquibase/changelog/20200425093313_updated_entity_Teacher
```

instead of

```
config/liquibase/changelog/20200425093313_updated_entity_Teacher.xml
```

Comment: I have the same on loadUpdateData, but file has the extension
included file db/changelog/2022/10/202210251017_add_vector_template_test.csv/db/changelog/2022/10/202210251017_add_vector_template_test.csv is not a recognized file type